Powershell- check and return properties of an object as a string
I have an object which sometimes is just one value:
`[DBG]: PS C:\Users\jmilano\Documents\PowerShell_Scripts\Hosts>> $ESXiPG.extensionData.Config.DefaultPortConfig.VLAN.vlanid
1009
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\jmilano\Documents\PowerShell_Scripts\Hosts>>And sometimes is two values:$ESXiPG.extensionData.Config.DefaultPortConfig.VLAN.vlanid
Start  End

108 108
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\jmilano\Documents\PowerShell_Scripts\Hosts>> `
I'm adding the object value(s) to a string so when the object contains 2 properties I need to combine them but I cannot get this to work?
When the object has 2 properties, this works OK:
`[DBG]: PS C:\Users\jmilano\Documents\PowerShell_Scripts\Hosts>> ($ESXiPG.extensionData.Config.DefaultPortConfig.VLAN.VLANID | Select @{Name="vLANIDx";Expression={$.Start,$.End -join "-"}})
vLANIDx
0-4094 `
However the same code results in an empty string when the object only has one property.

You need to force an array by adding @(....) around the property so when there is only one value the object is treated as an array.

I tried this:
$xxx = New-Object PSObject
$xxx | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name "a" -value "alpha"
$xxx | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name "b" -value "beta"
@($xxx.a, $xxx.b) -join "-"
The result was:
alpha-beta
Then I tried the same with a single variable value and it seemed to work.
Thanks
